# don't execute a function again while its executing

Tags: javascript

im currently making a game where you have to be able to walk, but when i hold down one of the walk buttons it keeps executing the function.

this is the code i have:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if(event.key==="d") {startMoveLeft();}
    if(event.key==="a") {startMoveRight();}
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key==="d") {stopMoveRight();}
    if(event.key==="a") {stopMoveRight();}
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key==="d") {stopMoveLeft();}
    if(event.key==="a") {stopMoveLeft();}
});

function startMoveRight() {
    movingRight = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left += 1;
            floor.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
}

function startMoveLeft() {
    movingLeft = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left -= 1;
            floor.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
}

function stopMoveRight() {
    clearInterval(movingRight);
}

function stopMoveLeft() {
    clearInterval(movingLeft);
}

var movingRight = false;
var movingLeft = false;
var movingUp = false;
var movingDown = false;
```

when i hold down D or A it slowly goes realy fast. so i need to block the "startmoveleft" function when its executing.

does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: if you want to stop it from running again you can use a flag which says if it is running or not and based on that you can prevent another run. However, I would suggest to use a counter. and make it run n number of times which is configurable. So that this kind of faster movement can actually be made a feature. Hope this helps

Comment: Just curious: why is "d" used to move left and "a" to move right?!?  "a" is left of "d" (ASD...)...

Comment: You can merge the second and third "keyup" event listeners.

Comment: How about another global var to hold key down if key down, and empty string/null when key up - say `key`?  Then, have an interval to check that value, and move accordingly?

Comment: Oh!!!  Are you using setInterval instead of setTimeout?

Comment: You don't need the `+ "px"` in `floor.style.left = left + "px";` - it's added by default.  I's use only if I wanted "%" or "em" or "rem" etc.

Comment: @iAmOren beacouse the map is bigger than the screen instead of moving the character i move the background, it looks and feels the same but i can make bigger maps. and thank you very much fgor responding and helping me!

Comment: That's smart!  (moving the background).  Perhaps change to `moveMap(direction)`?

Comment: @iAmOren thanks! You are right about the moveMap thing, im changing it rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key==="d") {stopMoveRight();}
    if(event.key==="a") {stopMoveRight();}
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key==="d") {stopMoveLeft();}
    if(event.key==="a") {stopMoveLeft();}
});
function startMoveRight() {
    movingRight = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left += 1;
            floor.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
}

function startMoveLeft() {
    movingLeft = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left -= 1;
            floor.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
}
```

Copy paste this

```
var direction = "";
function currentDirection(movingToDirection){
    if(movingToDirection != direction){
        stopMoveLeft()
        stopMoveRight()
        return true; 
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
    
}

function startMoveLeft() {

    if(currentDirection("left")){
        direction = "left";
    movingLeft = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left -= 1;
            floor.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
    }
}
function startMoveRight() {
    if(currentDirection("right")){
        direction = "right";
    movingRight = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(floor).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left += 1;
            floor.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
    }
}
```

Have fun with the game.

Comment: Hey! thanks for responding. i did as you said and it works now. but only to the left, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: it works now but when i release the key i cant move to that same direction again, only to the other one

Comment: under stopMoveRight and stopMoveLeft functions insert the following line: 
direction = "";
This will reset movement.